# c# Regex not working

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following code:

```
    content = Regex.Replace(content, "{%Pwd%}", pwd ?? "");
```

If pwd is null, I would expect it to be replaced with "" but it is still pulling it in as null.
Anyway, I can fix this. Also why is it not working as expected?

Comment: Are you sure `pwd` is not `"null"`, rather than `null`?

Comment: What does is the contents of pwd when hit? (Use a breakpoint).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I'd split this line into two:

```
string replacement = pwd ?? "";
content = Regex.Replace(content, "{%Pwd%}", replacement);
```

- What is the value of `replacement`?
- Is content being replaced with `"null"`?

I'm guessing it will be `"null"` or `""` as if replacement was `null` an `ArgumentNullException` would be thrown.

I'd also check that `{%Pwd%}` is the correct regular expression - becuase [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) doesn't recognise it, it well may need certain characters escaping.  Without `content` we can only guess.

If you check these things the answer should become apparent.

Comment: Probably the `null` vs `"null"` part, since escaping the `{` `}` had no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead, since `{}` has a special meaning in Regex:

```
content = Regex.Replace(content, "\{%Pwd%\}", pwd ?? "");
```

You needed to escape your curly braces.

**EDIT:** Apparently that doesn't matter in Regex, but it never hurts to escape anyway.

Comment: It doesn't matter in this case. That won't fix the problem.

Comment: Because they're used in this form: `{1,2}`. When it's not just numbers, it's unambiguous. It's probably good advice to escape them anyway and avoid surprises, but this is not the problem.